# How do I combine Bottom Navigation Bar with my Home activity after my Login Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, bottom-navigation-bar

I am trying to accomodate my bottom navigation view into my Home activity. I am not sure how do i link it to display the feature. So basically, once I log in, my activity_home.xml runs. I just want to add my Bottom_nav_view.xml inside it to display.

I am not sure what are the code needed for this, but Ill add the ones which I think are relevant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.fd_v1">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.FD_V1">
    <activity
        android:name=".Bottom_Nav_View"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_bottom_nav_view" />
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" />
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

  </manifest>
```

Activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeActivity"
android:backgroundTint="@color/yellow">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="410dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:paddingVertical="95dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="75dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="74dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="74dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Welcome!"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout" />


     </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_Bottom_nav_view.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/yellow"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavView">
</FrameLayout>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:itemIconSize="40dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu" >
  </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Home_actvity.class

```
package com.example.fd_v1;

   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

   import android.os.Bundle;

  public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
  }
  }
```